# How to go to the last active series after clicking drillUp button in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am not sure if this is a bug. Take the case of multi series drill down. After a legend item has been clicked, the series for the item is hidden and then we drill down. From here, if one drills up then it should go to last active state, i.e. multi series but with one series hidden. Instead of going to last active state, drill up goes to initial series data.

To reproduce, please goto [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/). Reproducible steps below the code.

$(function () {

```
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts multi-series drilldown'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click columns to drill down to single series. Click categories to drill down both.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: '2010',
        data: [{
            name: 'Republican',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'republican-2010'
        }, {
            name: 'Democrats',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'democrats-2010'
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'other-2010'
        }]
    }, {
        name: '2014',
        data: [{
            name: 'Republican',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'republican-2014'
        }, {
            name: 'Democrats',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'democrats-2014'
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'other-2014'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'republican-2010',
            data: [
                ['East', 4],
                ['West', 2],
                ['North', 1],
                ['South', 4]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'democrats-2010',
            data: [
                ['East', 6],
                ['West', 2],
                ['North', 2],
                ['South', 4]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'other-2010',
            data: [
                ['East', 2],
                ['West', 7],
                ['North', 3],
                ['South', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'republican-2014',
            data: [
                ['East', 2],
                ['West', 4],
                ['North', 1],
                ['South', 7]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'democrats-2014',
            data: [
                ['East', 4],
                ['West', 2],
                ['North', 5],
                ['South', 3]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'other-2014',
            data: [
                ['East', 7],
                ['West', 8],
                ['North', 2],
                ['South', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

});

1. Click on any legend item, say '2010'. It will hide the corresponding columns.
2. Drill down any xAxis category, say 'Republicans'. This will only show the chart for Republicans across for directions.
3. Click drillUpButton (Back to 2014). This will show the chart for both 2010 and 2014. Instead it should have shown only for 2014.

Comment: I think it is the normal functionality. If you would like to change this option, you may make custom function in drillup event. Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/eq2w4Lee/1/

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzBlachliński, that really helped.